# How to copy a substring from a text file using powershell

Tags: powershell

```
$result = Get-Content -Path D:\out.txt  
$grepString = $result | Select-String -Pattern "startpoint of the string"    
Write-Host $grepString
```

I used this code but it is printing only one line(when it get \n), But I want my output in containing rest of the lines

Comment: So you want the text as of a string `"startpoint of the string"`, all the way to the end? Is that **including** `"startpoint of the string"` ?

Comment: Could you please provide out.txt file text and expected output?

Comment: yes it prints only one line from the starting point and then terminates what to do for getting output to the end of the file

Comment: I see there is no option to provide the out.txt file how i can send you  that file please tell if you know

Comment: add the 1st few lines of the text of the `Out.txt` file to your Question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.Where()` extension method in `SkipUntil` mode:

```
$result = Get-Content -Path D:\out.txt  
$filteredResults = $result.Where({$_ -match "startpoint of the string"}, 'SkipUntil')
```

`$filteredResults` is now an list of the input strings from the first match till the end.